# How can I retrieve a SharePoint online OAuth access token for unit tests?

Tags: sharepoint-online, oauth, unit-testing

I'm using the [SharePoint 2013 Rest API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx) in my web-application and I want to write some unit tests.

GitHub has the notion of personal access token ([Creating a personal access token for the commande line](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/)) which is ideal for unit-tests.

Does SharePoint have a way to retrieve OAuth access tokens without going through the OAuth flow? I found a link ([Active Directory authentication scenarios](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api)) but I want to make requests on behalf of a specific user.

Comment: how about: http://spshell.blogspot.sg/2015/03/sharepoint-online-o365-oauth.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, SharePoint does not offer such an access token.

As an alternative one can generate a refresh token which is valid for 6 months. This refresh token can be used to retrieve a new access token without going through an OAuth flow.

Comment: How do we generate a refresh token?